# adding filter for alias statements

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
select 
   user_sid, 
   count(activation_date_id) as activations 
from daily_activation_fact
where ci_pid in (
   select 
      ci_pid 
   from riq_pidlist 
   where partner_code = 'x'
)
and activation_date_id between 20201101 and 20201130
group by 1
having count(activation_date_id) > 0
```

When I run the above code , I get no error but the out put still shows values which are null or 0
when I try to give this condition in where clause I get error
How do I filter the users who had done one or more activations

```
User ID | Activation
1.              Null
2                0
3               100
4.              Null
5                6
```

I want the put put to be as follows:

```
User ID | Activation
3              100
5                6
```

But using the having clause with > 0  is not helping me filter the 0’s and null values

Comment: What is "null or 0"?  Sample data, desired results, and an explanatio nof the logic would help.

Comment: The sample data is as follows:

Comment: `
User ID | Activation
1.              Null
2                0
3               100
4.              Null
5                6
`
I want the put put to be as follows:
`
User ID | Activation
3              100
5                6
`
But using the having clause with > 0  is not helping me filter the 0’s and null values

Comment: . .`COUNT()` *never* returns a `NULL` value.  There is something you are not including in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing but if you're asking how to go from that first table to the second table then the answer is simply:

```sql
select
    user_id,
    activation
from sample_table
where activation > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I filter the users who had done more one activation

You should be able to use:

```
having count(*) > 1
```

Or:

```
having activations > 1
```